# Excel VBA. Add 1 year to existing cell

Tags: excel, date, vba

Been stuck for a while. I hope someone can help me with my current issue, and point me to why I'm having error

> Object Required 424 error

[Here](https://postimg.org/image/4bruy8kqb/) is the sheet I'm working on, and here is my current code:

note: (me.cmbveh.value is a combo box on my vba form)

```
Dim v_name As String
Dim add_date As Date

v_name = Me.cmbveh.Value
add_date = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(v_name, Sheets("Vehicle Database").Range("F14:R33"), 13, False)

Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(v_name, Sheets("Vehicle Database").Range("F14:R33"), 13, False).Select
ActiveCell.Value = DateSerial(Year(add_date) + 1, Month(add_date), Day(add_date))
```

The error is pointing in this line of code:

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(v_name, Sheets("Vehicle Database").Range("F14:R33"), 13, False).Select
```

What I'm trying to do here is, if the value on my combo box has a match on my table, I would like to be able to add 1 year on the "Registration Expiry Date" column.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I assume your code is inside your User_Form code, in which event is it placed ? `ComboBox_Change` ?

Comment: @ShaiRado it is inside Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Thank you

Comment: @ShaiRado Please tell me if you need additional information. Really need help with this one.

Comment: It will be helpful to know what values are you tring to look in the `VLookup` ? is it column I "Plate Number" ?

Comment: @ShaiRado my lookup value is the 'MAKE / MODEL & YEAR' column.

Comment: @ShaiRado Also, my combo box (cmbveh) contains all the data on my "MAKE / MODEL & YEAR" column. Hope it helps! Thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you know you are looking to compare your `cmbveh` Combo-Box value, with the values in Column F, you can use the `Application.Match` to find the row number that matches the value in the Combo-Box. Afterwards, you can get the row refference (add 13 to it, since your Range starts from row 14 and not row 1), and read the value from Column "R" (where you store your "REGISTRATION EXPIRY DATE").

At last, use the `DateAdd` function to add 1 year to exisitng date (by choosing `"yyyy"` as the interval parameter).

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim v_name As String
Dim add_date As Date

Dim MatchRow    As Variant

v_name = Me.cmbveh.Value

With Sheets("Vehicle Database")
    ' first test to see if Match criteria was met (found in Column F)
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(v_name, .Range("F14:F33"), 0)) Then
        MatchRow = Application.Match(v_name, .Range("F14:F33"), 0) '<-- get row number
        .Range("R" & MatchRow + 13).Value = DateAdd("yyyy", 1, .Range("R" & MatchRow + 13).Value)
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: It works! Please explain the codes for my future reference :)

Thank you very much!

Comment: @KelvinJhonCamua see edited post, I've added explanaition at the top, and some comments inside the code

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Would you mind if I ask another question? It is connected to this issue. It is about my formula keeps on changing values after testing.

Comment: which formula ?

Comment: This one: 

=IFERROR(INDEX('Renewal Tracker'!$D$2:$D$500,SMALL(IF('Renewal Tracker'!A$2:A$500=$I$10,ROW('Renewal Tracker'!D$2:D$500)-ROW('Renewal Tracker'!$D2)+1),ROWS('Renewal Tracker'!D$2:D2))),"") 

From:    
    INDEX('Renewal Tracker'!$D$2:$D$500 ROWS('Renewal Tracker'!D$2:D2))) 

To:
    INDEX('Renewal Tracker'!$D$3:$D$500 ROWS('Renewal Tracker'!D$2:D3)))

This happens when I run my my [FORM](https://postimg.org/image/51bxlvvr1/) to test it, and then delete the results (the rows it created on another sheet) afterwards.

Comment: @KelvinJhonCamua this is not related to your post at all. You should open a new post, describe what you are trying to acheive with this formula, the error, and upload your relevent code (it will allow other users to assist you as well)